# vim plugin youcompleteme for project using scons and g++ compiler

Tags: c++, vim, youcompleteme

I just installed YCM on CentOS 7.   I am now at the step of generating a ".ycm_extra_conf.py" equivalent of the file for my project, which is a nested directory of c++ files, uses Scons build system and g++ (with -std=c++98) to compile the c++ files.
I have  few questions:

1. Are the contents of the "flags" variable in ".ycm_extra_conf.py"
   file the flags that are passed to the project compiler, in my case
   the g++ compiler by the scons build system?
2. If answer to question 1 is yes, are these same flags then passed to
   clang when YCM compiles the files?   If so, is YCM compiling or more
   technically processing the c++ files in the project to use for
   semantic completion?
3. If answer to question 2 is yes, then I am guessing the flags I state in
   the "flags" variable will not work for clang, as they are applicable to
   g++.  Should I do a conversion/mapping of the flags to clang?
4. Does YCM use clang to only front-end compile the files to produce the
   AST to use for semantic completion?

Sorry about the naive questions, I am very new to YCM.  Any help/guidance would be very appreciated.

Regards and thank you,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get autocompletion working in vim with ycm is bear:

https://github.com/rizsotto/Bear

Install it and then just run:

bear scons

and you'll get your compilation database that makes  ycm happy.